# How does this python method invoke work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, methods

```
class Grid(QFrame):

    def generate(self):

        self.pen = False
        self.tgDig = False
        self.rwDig = False
```

I'm not sure how this works.

The `generate` method is defined with `self` as a parameter and I understand that all methods must have a special first parameter, usually called `self` but I don't understand how the `self` invokes `pen` or `tgDig` or `rwDig` since they don't exist anywhere else?

It's using PyQt QFrame if that helps.

Comment: That snippet is from a Class?

Comment: @algui91 Yes, edited code to add class.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is refering to the object that owns the method `generate`, it looks like `pen`, `tgDig`, and `rwDig` are also members of this same class or its parent class in the case of inheritance (etc. etc.).

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained) might be of some use.

Comment: But they don't occur anywhere else, not sure how they're members of the same class.

Comment: After your edit it seems like the variables may exist in a parent class, or its parent class etc. etc.  If thats not the case, does this cod run?

Comment: Yes, the code runs, yet I can't find the declarations of the variables in those classes.

Comment: There's no need of a declaration, if they didn't already exist they are just created on the fly. In Python objects are in many aspects dictionaries with some syntax sugar, and you can create attributes dynamically as you would add an element to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

All the methods of a class in Python have as first parameter `self`, which is a reference to the object itself. Like `this` in Java or C++. So in your example the three variables are members of the class, and you accesses it with `self`.

In your concrete example, you do not see the variables in the class because they are inherited from another class (`QFrame`). The syntax for a class to inherit from another is `class MyClass(ParentClass)`

Comment: I don't see how they're inherited from that class as they don't exist in the class?

Comment: They don't exsists in QFrame? Then QFrame inherit from another class, keep looking for the parent class and you should find those variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the examples you will see the [method resolution order](http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/python-tutorial-understanding-python-mro-class-search-path) and the `base` class that `Grid` inherits its attributes and methods from.

```
import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)#
from PyQt4.QtGui import QFrame,QApplication   
class Grid(QFrame):

    def generate(self):

        self.pen = False
        self.tgDig = False
        self.rwDig = False

import inspect
print inspect.getmro(Grid)
print(Grid.__bases__)
```